# Why are models not imported when connecting to database using mongoose.connect?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When I connect to my MongoDb instance using the following code

```
var MongoDbConnection = null;
var databaseUrl = "xxxxx";

mongoose.connect(databaseUrl);
mongoose.connection.once('open', onDatabaseConnectionOpen);
mongoose.connection.on('error', onDatabaseConnectionError);

function onDatabaseConnectionOpen() {
    MongoDbConnection = mongoose.connection;
    console.log(mongoose);
    console.log(mongoose.connection);
}

function onDatabaseConnectionError(err) {
    console.log("Error connecting to MongoDb database");
    console.log(err);

}
```

the `models` property in `mongoose` is an empty object `{}`.

The schema and models have been initialized in a different repository. My expectation was that by connecting to the database I would be able to fetch the models as well (to make further queries on the database).

When I add the following lines at the start of the code

```
const Model1 = require('./models/Model1.js')
const Model2 = require('./models/Model2.js')
const Model3 = require('./models/Model3.js')
const Model4 = require('./models/Model4.js')
```

the respective models and schemas show up in the `mongoose.connection` object.

Example of Model1.js

```
var mongoose        =   require('mongoose');
var Schema          =   mongoose.Schema;

var model1Schema = new Schema({

    prop1: String,
    prop2: String,
    prop3: String

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('model1', model1Schema);
```

Is there a way to load the models and schemas when I connect to the database using `mongoose.connect` or do I need to require the models in this file to make database queries?

Comment: MongoDB is a *schemaless* database and Mongoose allows you to implement a schema on the application-layer, so yes, you need to include the schema definitions for mongoose to use them.

Comment: @Sven I'm porting this code from Python to Nodejs. But I didn't have this problem when I was using PyMongo in Python. I didn't have to include the schema definitions there and was able to make queries to the individual collections. Would you know why is there the difference in behavior?

Comment: You're using Mongoose, which is a schema wrapper over the official [`mongodb`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/installation-guide/installation-guide/) driver. Since MongoDB is a schemaless database, Mongoose will need schema definitions. If you instead use the raw driver, you could query it `db.collection('myCollection').find(...)`. I advice against using Mongoose, because it is an application-layer schema implementation for a database that doesn't have schemas. If your application needs schemas, you should use a database that enforces schemas (pgsql, mysql, etc).

Comment: Thanks @Sven. Got your point. About using Mongoose, I'm still in the early stages of the application I'm building and so I'm not sure about the exact schema that would need to be in place. Assuming that making changes to the schema would be more difficult in a relational database I went ahead with mongoDb and mongoose for the time